# How do I split a String into 2 different types?

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string "201607" and I need to split it to 2 separate types. 2016 into int and 07 into byte. I have seen string split functions which all use delimeters but that won't work here. Is there an easier way to do this or so I have to split it into chars and then reconstruct them in C#?

Comment: So.. `Substring()`, `int.Parse()` and `byte.Parse()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wqkolp)

```
string input="201607";
int integerPart=0;      
if(int.TryParse(input.Substring(0,4),out integerPart))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Integer value is {0}",integerPart);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Conversion Failed");
}
byte bytePart = byte.Parse(input.Substring(4));
Console.WriteLine("Byte Part is {0}",bytePart);
```

Comment: @Scar : Glad to hear that from you. Happy to help you

Answer (score 2):

Try it also:

```
string input="201607";
int IntPart=Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(0,4));
byte BytePart=Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this too:

```
var input = "201607";
var matches = Regex.Match(input, "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})");
var integerPart = int.Parse(matches.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value);
var bytePart = byte.Parse(matches.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value);
```